# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) javascript/application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Running my ROR app with Puma locally. Getting the following error trying to load javascript/application.js

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) javascript/application.js
```

Keep in mind this was a Ruby 1.9.3 app that I just updated the GEM file to 2.3.1

Does anything need to be changed when running a Rails app locally?

The source code shows

```
  <script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
  <link href="/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally, javascript files should be under `app/assets/javascripts`. They will be compressed, minified and copied into `public` during assets compilation (deployment)

Looks like there's no js files under `/public/javascripts` hence the 404 error you are getting.

It's also worth checking that you are starting the app in development mode. Otherwise, rails will look into `public` for js and css files.

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in my projects there is this kind of path

```
/assets/js/...
```

but maybe earlier was diffrent convetion.

Do you use static assets or dynamic on local ?